# Using FCM with django and flutter

Tags: django, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, django-push-notifications

I have a django backend server and I want to send notification to my flutter app. I want to use **Firebase Cloud Messaging** for this.

My question is, do I need to store something in my database to send notification to the app? I was planning to use **django_push_notification** on the backend side.

Comment: You need to store device ids called register device id and send them push notification. You find also library for  that. If new post will publish send notification to register device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store the device id on the server to be able to send push notifications to your app. You can use this django app to expose rest endpoints the id registration and sending notifications: https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django